# Django's makemigrations with RegexValidator throws TypeError

Tags: django, django-1.7, django-validation, django-migrations

I'm updating my app for Django 1.7 and tried to `python manage.py makemigrations` with the result of the following error:

`TypeError: unbound method deconstruct() must be called with RegexValidator instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`

MyModel:

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, validators=[RegexValidator])
```

In real it's more complicated but I think that causes the error. I'm using Python 2.7.

I've read the Django docs about [migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/) including [Adding a deconstruct() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#adding-a-deconstruct-method) and about [RegexValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/validators/#django.core.validators.RegexValidator) but I don't understand how to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass an instance of regex validator instead of type:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, validators=[RegexValidator(your_regex)])
```